# C++11 iterator interface

Tags: c++, generics, c++11, iterator

Is it possible to create in `C++11` a function, which will accept any `iterator` as input argument in particular stl containers like `vector` or `list`?

I want to write something like

```
void f(iterator<int> i){
   for (auto el : i)
      cout << el;
}
int main(){
   vector<int> v;
   list<int> l;
   ...
   f(v);
   f(l);
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Make it a template?

Comment: Of course ... Thank you - I have forgotten that when you make function template you can use it without providing the template type explicite.

Comment: Are you looking for `RangeS`? A single iterator is not very useful.

Comment: What is `RangeS`? It is from `boost::range`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can write a function template that accepts any iterator as parameter, but not a function.

If you had a class that did type erasure for iterators then you could take that as a parameter. Here's [an article and code for iterator type erasure](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want your function to accept an iterator, then you cannot use the `for (auto i: cont)` syntax. Indeed, this new range-based for syntax wants the container, not an iterator.

Then, your can easily make your function a function template, passing the container.

```
template <class CONT>
void f(CONT &cont){
    for (auto el : cont)
        cout << el;
}
```

If you want to keep passing iterators, then you'll have to go the template way too, but you have to pass two iterators as arguments. One for the first, another for the last (just like the `algorithm` does).

```
template <class IT>
void f(IT first, IT last) {
    for ( ; first!=last ; ++first)
        cout << first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a boost::any_iterator somewhere. But the Standard does not provide one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to *return* a mostly unspecified iterator type (e.g. because the function signature in a base class can't fix the exact type of the iterator yet), you could have a look at [C++: "Iterable<T>" interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67335987/3907364)